# Установится ли Вайбер и Телеграм на андроид 4.4.2?

Tags: android, telegram, viber

подскажите, кто знает, установится ли актуальная версия вайбер и телеграм на андроид 4.4.2? Если нет, то **будет ли работать старая версия?** В гугле устаревшая информация, 2018 года.

Comment: А почему вы об этом спрашиваете здесь? Пробуйте сами или спрашивайте в темах этих приложений в соц.сетях/форумах. Скорее всего новые не установятся из-за ограничения на минимальную версию ОС, а старые не будут работать из-за устаревших сертификатов и/или изменений на серверной стороне

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что не по теме

Comment: [Telegram FOSS](https://github.com/Telegram-FOSS-Team/Telegram-FOSS) последней версии 9.6.5 может быть установлен на Android 4.4 и выше. Скачать и установить можно [из F-Droid маркета](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/org.telegram.messenger/).

Answer (score 1):

Тестировал на Android 4.4

Telegram версии `9.6.7` работает без проблем (звонки не проверял), Viber версии `15.8.0.6` работает, общаться можно (синхронизацию не проверял, звонки не проверены т.к. не кому)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Буду пробовать.